# On Error catch block did not call

Tags: c#

In an Interview,Interviewer asked to me.. that
I have a code which written in side the try and catch block like

```
try
 {
 //code line 1
 //code line 2
 //code line3 -- if  error occur on this line then did not go in the catch block
 //code line 4
 //code line 5
 }
 catch()
 {
  throw
 }
```

suppose we got an error on code line 3
then this will not go in the catch block
but If I got error on any other line except line 3 it go in catch block

is this possible that if error occur on a particular line then it is not go in the catch block?

Comment: Unplug the power chord from your computer at the moment line 3 is executed :)

Comment: The OOM and SO exceptions are hard (impossible?)  to catch.

Comment: What was the actual interview question? How to make it so line 3 doesn't cause the catch block to be entered, or given that code, what possible thing could line 3 be doing that would prevent the catch from catching anything?

Comment: @David: Question was "How to make it so line 3 doesn't cause the catch block to be entered"

Comment: Do you get an Error or an Exception at line 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap line 3 in another `try/catch` block:

```
try
{
    //code line 1
    //code line 2
    try
    {
        //code line3 -- if  error occur on this line then did not go in the catch block
    }
    catch { }
    //code line 4
    //code line 5
}
catch()
{
    throw;
}
```

Also the interviewer must have defined *error*. Was talking about an exception as an *error* could mean many things => crappy code, exception, not behaving as expected code, ...

Comment: I deleted my answer. `ThreadAbortException` can be caught but it is raised again at the end of the catch block.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: I didn't down vote, so no confusion here. but I wanted to comment on your ans anyway. Your ans still does not clarify why it didn't catch the exception. your solution sitll won't work if it is catch() with parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If you line 3 causes `non CLS-compliant exceptions`, it won't be catch'ed with parameterized catch() block. To catch all type of exceptions, use parameterless catch block.

```
try
{
// Statement which causes an exception
}

catch //No parameters
{
//Handles any type of exception
}
```

[.net Exception catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345436/net-exception-catch-block/5345456#5345456)

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Yes

There are errors that a catch block will not get. I think out of memory error. Another way an Exception can skip a block is if the error thrown is not one of the ones you defined.